# simple rank formula

Tags: math, formula, rank

I'm looking for a mathmatical ranking formula.

Sample is

```
    2008    2009    2010
A   5       6       4
B   6       7       5
C   7       8       2
```

I want to add a rank column for each period code field

```
                            rank
    2008    2009    2010    2008    2009    2010
B   6       7       5       2       1       1
A   5       6       4       3       2       2
C   7       2       2       1       3       3
```

please do not reply with methods that loop thru the rows and columns, incrementing the rank value as it goes, that's easy.  I'm looking for a *formula* much like finding the percent total (item / total).  I know i've seen this before but an havning a tough time locating it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the question... is it just me.. or?

Comment: So the row with the biggest entry under 2008 has rank 1, the one with second-biggest has rank 2, etc?

Comment: He wants to compute the position or rank of an element in an unordered group.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of different sorting algorithms. Perhaps one of those is what you're thinking of? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: You can't have a formula for the rank unless it's simply a wrapper around an order(n lg n) search (best case, n^2 worst) like rank(int r)...

Comment: In short, the "easy" method is THE way to do it. Otherwise your best case will be (n^2 lg n) when it should only be (n lg n).

Comment: how you want it? Pseudo code? SQL? Programming Language?

Comment: I'm looking for a formula, the correct answer would apply to any language or a pencil and paper.

Comment: Is this for an arbitrary size sets, or just three?

Answer (score 4):

sort ((letters_col, number_col) descending by number_col)

As efficient as your sort alg.

Then number the rows, of course

### Edit

I really got upset by your comment *"please don't up vote this answer, sorting and loop is not what I'm asking for. i specifically stated this in my original question. "* , and the negative votes, because, as you may have noted by the various answers received, it's basically correct.

However, I remained pondering where and how you may "have seen this before".

Well, I think I got the answer: You saw this in Excel.

Look at this:

[image]

This is the result after entering the formulas and sorting by column H.

It's exactly what you want ...

Comment: OK show me the formula...  as i stated in my question, sorting and looping to get the answer is plain simple and doesn't merit a question.

Comment: @Graham: ranking and sorting are essentially the same thing. Sorry if that does not satisfy you.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using?  If you're using Excel, you're looking for RANK(num, ref).

```
=RANK(B2,B$2:B$9)
```

I don't know of any programming language that has that built in, it would always require a loop of some form.

Comment: yup know about the RANK function in Excel.  I'm doing this in an ADO.NET dataset.  i have numerous columns with many rows that need a rank value.  Currently I’m sorting and adding an incrementing value.  Works but i was just thinking there has got to be a more efficient way..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rank of a *single* element, you can do it in O(n) by looping through the elements, counting how many have value above the given element, and adding 1.

If you want the rank of *all* the elements, the best (and really only) way is to sort the elements.  Anything else you do will be equivalent to sorting (there is no "formula")

Answer (score 0):

Are you using T-SQL?  [T-SQL RANK()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) may pull what you want.